# Do trinitarians believe it would be possible for God to incarnate as a non-human animal?

Tags: trinity, incarnation

Trinitarians believe that God, who is Spirit, could have and did become a human. On the other hand, unitarians tend not to believe that God could have become a human, as it would entail a contradiction in his nature. God cannot do things against God's nature.

Do trinitarians believe that God could also become a different non-human animal if he so chose, or are the capabilities of a human required for an incarnation?

Comment: Are you asking whether it is possible for a disembodied spirit to enter an animal body? I think Mark 5:11-13 answers this: *11 A large herd of pigs was feeding on the nearby hillside. 12 **The demons begged Jesus, “Send us among the pigs; allow us to go into them.”** 13 He gave them permission, **and the impure spirits came out and went into the pigs**. The herd, about two thousand in number, rushed down the steep bank into the lake and were drowned.*

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator No, not a spirit. God.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator Equivalent to how trinitarians view the incarnation, but a non-human animal.

Comment: Even if it were possible, what would be the point?

Comment: I'm confused by your opening sentence. Trinitarians believe that the Word, or Logos, who was with God in the beginning and who was part of the One Being of God, agreed to give up the glory he had in heaven and condescended to become human - a little lower than the angels. God, the Father, remained as Spirit.  Father, Son and Holy Spirit were all present at the baptism of Jesus. When Jesus died, the Father and the Holy Spirit did not also die. There are three parts to the One Being of God. Is that what you believe?

Comment: @Lesley Are you asking whether I'm a trinitarian or whether your summary is accurate re standard trinitarian belief? Do you think the 1st sentence is incompatible with what you just described?

Comment: I'm aware that there are Christians who do not subscribe to the orthodox view I've tried to explain. Some say the Father alone is God. Some say that God can appear as either the Son or the Holy Spirit.  Your opening sentence does not adequately describe the Trinitarian view and that's why I'm confused.

Comment: @Lesley I think I understand what you're saying. I'm simply setting up the statement about becoming a human (Spirit -> becoming a human). I'm not trying to distinguish or make any interesting theological claims here - just quoting John 4:24.

Answer (score 8):

Since God created only the man and the woman, not animals, in His image, you are correct in saying that for God to become an animal would be against His nature.

That is not to say that God never used animals to accomplish his will. The classic illustration is found in Numbers, Chapter 22. God was angry with the prophet Balaam, and the angel of the LORD (a pre-incarnate appearance of Jesus Christ?) let Balaam know via his donkey that he was headed for disaster. Because Balaam was intent on disobeying God, he was not aware of the awesome presence of the angel of the LORD, but his donkey was! Not until Balaam had beaten his poor donkey three times did God open Balaam's eyes to the danger he faced.

My point is that God does not despise animals, or treat them with contempt. On the contrary, He cares for them. The last verses of the book of Jonah tell us the reason God refused to destroy Ninevah was out of concern for both its citizens ***and*** its many animals (4:10-11)!

As for trinitarians, of whom I am one, they believe God in eternity past had a plan to rescue the human race from sin. In the eternal counsels of the Triune God, the Godhead determined that the Savior of humankind would be God's only beloved Son, who at the fulness of time was conceived by the Holy Spirit, born of the virgin Mary, born under the Law that he might redeem those who were under the curse of having broken God's Law.

In conclusion, the redemption of humankind could have been achieved by no other means than by the death of Jesus Christ, whom the Bible has revealed to be both the lion of the tribe of Judah, and the Lamb of God who takes away the sin of the world. The lion and the lamb are metaphors, of course, but God chose them to be symbols for His Christ. The lion speaks of the ferocity of the Christ, who will execute judgment on rebellious and unrepentant mankind in the great and awesome Day of the Lord.

The lamb speaks of God's perfect sacrificial Lamb, who was led to the slaughter, willingly and silently, and who by the shedding of his blood made cleansing from sin and forgiveness possible for those who believe.